Adding Pre-order option to stock status in product
I want to add an extra option in the "stock status" part of a product. I never use backorders, but want to set some products in Pre-order state instead of in or out of stock.
When I pre-order normally, I add 100 to the stock, so they are as per Magento "in stock".
After checking with my go-to developer, they said that there is no possibility to have another product state as in or out stock, and would love to add a third option to that pull down menu.
As for me, this sounds really simple to do, in practice this is not always the case, so I want to double-check if it really is not possible to "just add another option" to that pull down menu.
Nothing has to change, so basically a copy of "in stock", but called "pre-order", so I only have to change the status to in stock when the product arrives.

I don't have any form of problem with 3rd party modules, but most of them use Sellable Quantities, which I have disabled, because of it making a mess I could not fix by myself.
The reason I don't want backorders enabled, is that I sell quite a lot of hard to get product I want to manage in my time, not the customer's demand. When one backorders such product, I have to deliver and pay a lot (thus lose money by having to order large amounts) to have it delivered to the customer.
None of my products are with negative stock and I want to keep it that way, that's the reason I wanted to (for my idea) make it as easy as possible by just altering the Stock pull down menu per product. An extra option or tag in that menu would enable me to set it to 100 stock and take it off of pre-order when the correct amount of stock comes in, without altering the product itself or be afraid of products I don't want ordered.
Is this something one could program, or is the menu either IN STOCK or OUT OF STOCK or do I have to go look for a module?

You have a lot of options on 3rd party extension to manage this situation. Just look up for "magento 2 pre-order extension free" and you will find 3rd party options with lots of configuration options to manage your case.
In case you don't want to go with other than Magento, you can review the OMS system (which is a separated service see info) which allows to manage that specifically.
Magento already has the backorders as you mention (see docs here).
Why the option to allow backorders it not good for your case?

Based on your last response, you want to have a "incoming soon", but not allow to purchase the item when is in that state. Does the "alert me when back in stock" functionality work in your case? See this. With some theming you might be able to get to show "in stock" but get a subscription  for when the item is in stock for those that are interested.

@maikel-tegelaers see my last comment please.
